# Android App Copyright Issue

Tags: android, google-play

At present I am using older design for Developer Console. Now for my app I have selected the off option in Copyright section. Just from few days a notification is coming in the home page of my developer console that Copyright feature has been deprecated, we should use Licensing service. If I am changing to new version design, I am not getting any such notification in home page. But I am comfortable with older design, so I am using older one. Now just want to clarify that anything I have to worry about or not (Because I have not enabled the copyright feature)?????? Any ideas are welcome...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depends on that you are afraid of.

The reason why a Licensing service or Copyright is used, is to protect your code from being copied, or used without your consent.

Because you already choose the off option, the new changes aren't effecting your settings. But my tip, use the setting/service, better safe than sorry.